# JQuery change radio to 'checked' on event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following HTML and JS with [bootstrap-switch.org](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) to switch between to groups of radio buttons in a form. However, I'm having trouble getting the first radio button in the second group to be 'checked' by default when its group is activated/shown.:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Form Group</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <!-- Bootstrap switch checkbox -->
        <div class="switch">
            <input id="optswitch" type="checkbox" name="opt_switch" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info" data-on-text="Group 1" data-off-text="Group 2" checked>
        </div>
        <!-- /Bootstrap switch checkbox -->

    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="keysize">Form Options</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            <div class="gp1">
                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="keysize" data-label="2048bit" id="keysize1" value="2048" checked>
                </label>

                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="keysize" data-label="3072bit" id="keysize2" value="3072" >
                </label>

                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="keysize" data-label="4096bit" id="keysize3" value="4096" >
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="gp2" style="display:none">
                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="keysize" data-label="256bit" id="keysize4" value="256">
                </label>

                <label class="radio-inline custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="keysize" data-label="384bit" id="keysize5" value="384" >
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

**JS** *(Using JQuery 1.10.2)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("[name='opt_switch']").bootstrapSwitch();

                $('#optswitch').on('switchChange', function (e, data) {
                    var $el = $(data.el),
                        value = data.value;
                    if(value){//this is true if the switch is on
                       $('.gp1').show();
                       $('.gp2').hide();
                       $('#keysize1').prop('checked', true);
                    }else{
                       $('.gp2').show();
                       $('.gp1').hide();
                       $('#keysize4').prop('checked', true); 
                    }
                });

            });
```

It seems to work in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnexb/). But not in my environment.
But I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I'm also using [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/), but I'm guessing that shouldn't affect the behaviour of the switch?

**UPDATE 2**
Looks like it is an issue with [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/). This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GYHk/1/) shows the issue. Still can't figure why prettyCheckable it's not updating with `.prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with prettyCheckable. The radio change via `.prop('checked', true)` does happen, prettyCheckable just doesn't reflect it.

The plugin does have a ['Check/Uncheck' method](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/#methods), but I couldn't get it to work.

Adding `.next('a').addClass('checked');` or `.next('a').removeClass('checked');` after `.prop('checked', true/false)` resolves the issue:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.custom-checkbox input, .custom-radio input').prettyCheckable();    
        $("[name='opt_switch']").bootstrapSwitch();

            $('#optswitch').on('switchChange', function (e, data) {
                var $el = $(data.el),
                    value = data.value;
                if(value){//this is true if the switch is on
                   $('.gp1').show();
                   $('.gp2').hide();
                   $('#keysize4').next('a').removeClass('checked');
                   $('#keysize5').next('a').removeClass('checked');
                   $('#keysize1').prop('checked', true).next('a').addClass('checked');
                }else{
                   $('.gp2').show();
                   $('.gp1').hide();
                   $('#keysize1').next('a').removeClass('checked');
                   $('#keysize2').next('a').removeClass('checked');
                   $('#keysize3').next('a').removeClass('checked');
                   $('#keysize4').prop('checked', true).next('a').addClass('checked');
                }
            });

        });
```

The above works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GYHk/5/)), but I'm not sure it's the best solution.